# Форматирование результатов запроса средствами MySQL

Tags: mysql

В таблице MySQL хранятся целые числа: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и тд.

Есть ли возможность средствами MySQL отформатировать результат запроса, чтобы получить: 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 и тд

Comment: update -ом пройтись по столбцу =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LPAD(`number`, 2, '0') from `table`
```

Одна проблемка: начиная со 100 числа будут обрубаться до двух цифр.

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я, к сожалению, не знаю mysql, но в Oracle можно:

```
SELECT '0'||to_str(number) from tab;
```

**||** - знак склеивания лексем. Может быть и в mysql есть что-нибудь подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
select substring( cast( ( 1000 + number ) as varchar ), 2, 3 ) from table
```

Или так:

```
select
  replicate( '0', 10 - len( num ) ) + num
from
  (
    select
      cat( number as varchar ) as num
    from
      table
  ) t
```

Функции из MSSQL, но легко найти аналог в MySQL